# What controller should i use?

Tags: bluetooth, shields, hardware

I'm working on a little DIY project in which I intend to make my own dataglove. Now I'm kinda stuck on choosing the right microcontroller. And since it can be quite costly, I thought to ask for some help.

So: I'm going to use 12 flex sensors (maybe 14) and 1 IMU (probably the 6050). now the problem is that I need a total of at least 14 AI.. And the small controllers only have about 6.

The controller can't be too big for dexterity reasons and also will need the availability to add a Bluetooth module.

I've been looking at some multiplexing/shield options but I'm just not confident (and rich) enough start ordering..

Peace out,

Lars

PS: other brands besides Arduino work for me to

Comment: Use suppliers parametric searches. I use PIC32 mainly, and I know they have plenty of analog inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a Teensy? The guys that make Teensy have developed many of the well known Arduino libraries and have also helped develop the Arduino IDE in the past so they know their stuff.

I see the Teensy LC at about $11. the spec says its almost the same as Teensy 3.1 which has 20+ Analog In

https://www.pjrc.com/store/teensylc.html

https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/index.html

The 3.1 and 3.6 are more powerful and more expensive at around $29

note: Read the index for which boards are 5v tolerant if that's what you need.